# simple form for style

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, simple-form-for

Good afternoon. I had a problem in styles . I have a table with data , but using simple_form_for I lost distance between the label and the window placeholder. Before that, I used the following code , and now I have a problem , there is nothing in a head climbs

My code :

```
tr
 td
  = user.input :current_password, label: 'Пароль', placeholder: 'Введите текущий пароль'
```

code before :

```
tr
  td
    | Новый пароль:
  td
    = user.password_field :password
```

Answer (score 0):

The below should work

```
tr
 td
  = user.label 'Пароль'
  = user.input :current_password, label: false, placeholder: 'Введите текущий пароль'
```

Comment: dublicate of label.  
label 'Пароль'  &  label 'current_passwod'

Comment: Big thx Pavan. It work :) But i want to inside 2 string at the one. i will be think about it...